# Filter Combobox Items Based on Values in a 2nd Column

Tags: c#

I have a Datatable(invTable) with 19 columns in it that I created from a csv file. From that Datatable I'm using the values in column2(name) to populate a Combobox.

What I need to do is filter the items from column2(name) that show up in the Combobox only if the value in column9(type) matches a preset value. i.e. only if the value in column9(type) is 15.

I also need to be able to work with the values in the rest of the columns based on the selected item in the Combobox. Assigning them to variables such as SelectedCol1-SelectedCol19 so that they can be used in other calculations throughout the program.

EDIT:
I was able to find something that suited my needs with the following code.

```
var query = invTable.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.Field<String>("Type").Equals("15"));
combo1.DataSource = query.AsDataView();
combo1.DisplayMember = "name";
combo1.ValueMember = "Index";
```

Comment: what I'd do (if you've not already done it) is re-factor this into a method. The method will have two parameters, the the field name ("type" in the example) and the value ("15" in th example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to attempt to give you a complete solution here but I do hope ot send you in the right direction.

Basically you need to use a DataView (which is the "filtered" view of the original DataSet. So each time yo want to filter, you'll create a DataView assigning it the filter criteria.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx

The link above should give you a working solution. Towards the bottom of the age they also have examples.

Once you have your DataView filtered the way you need to, you can iterate over it's rows to populate the drop downs in question.

**Edited** to provide simple steps for the OP.

Start simple. I'm assuming you know how to populate a ComboBox.

Step1: Get the Data in a DataSet
Step2: Filter the DataSet using a DataView
Step3: Populate the ComboBox using the DataView (instead of the DataSet)

pseudo code:

```
DataSet dt = GetInvDataTable();
DataView dv = new DataView(dt, "type = 15", null,
        DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Now you can use the DataView (the variable dv) to populate your CombobBox just like you were doing initially with the DataSet.

If you're using BindingSource then simply set the DataSource of the BindingSource to your DataView (dv in this case).

You don't mention the .NET version you're using but if you're using 3.5 or 4 you could also use linq to filter your DataSet. You'll need to add the DataSetExtensions assembly as a reference to you project.

```
DataTable invDataTable = GetInvDataTable();

EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query =
    from inv in invDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    where order.Field<int>("type") == 15
    select inv;

DataView dv = query.AsDataView();

bindingSource1.DataSource = dv;
```

Comment: @John, don't know what happened there... deleted the earlier one

Comment: Thanks for the directions, I'll check it out. I think my main issue is it's too "simple"? I have a hard time grasping things like where to put a ; but I can code a complex stock market type system with 100's of variables all interacting without batting an eyelash :/ I'm much better at debugging then actually coding.

Comment: @Jason - I've edited my answer to hopefully provide with with the steps.

Comment: Thank you for your help Shiv. For whatever reason tho I couldn't get your example to work for me. I was however able to figure out a different way of doing it which seems to be slightly more suitable for my needs? Considering I have around 30 ComboBoxes that needed the invTable filtered and displayed.

Comment: @Jason, the concept is the same, All you've done is put the code I gave you in one line and you've used the Enumerable methods instead of "query expression syntax".